# How to make syntax color default again in eclipse? I installed color theme - it does not work

Tags: eclipse, syntax-highlighting, color-scheme

[image: pic]

I installed some color scheme from this website http://eclipsecolorthemes.org/?view=theme&id=1, but it does not work! it only shows black screen & white font!

How to undo that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Window -> Preferences -> General -> Appearance -> Color Theme`, choose "Default"

However, from your screenshot it looks like you have opened your Java files in the plain text editor rather than the Java editor.  This will also cause you to have no syntax highlighting.  Try right-clicking a Java file and do `Open With -> Java Editor`.